# How do you add multi-line text to a Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

How to declare Button struct to display multiline strings?

```
   import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView : View {
        var body: some View {
            return Button("Line 1 \n Line 2") {}
        }
    }
```

[image: ui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Button` method [`lineLimit(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/3264282-linelimit)

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
          Button("Hello World").lineLimit(nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You code return error `Missing argument for parameter 'label' in call`

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiline `Button` then you can implement it like this.

```
 Button(action: {
          print("Action goes here")
       }, label: {
           Text("Line 1 \n Line 2").lineLimit(nil)
       })
```